# Symfony2: ACL permit access to routes with keys

Tags: security, symfony, acl, roles

I have some CRUD routing:

```
/news/{page} // public
/news/new    // private
/news/{slug}/show  //public
/news/{slug}/edit  //private
/news/{slug}/delete  //private
```

What placeholder do I have to set at access_controll in security.yml?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.+` e.g

```
    - { path: ^/news/.+/show, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Comment: Thank ya :D

Does the route use regex?

Comment: Yes you can set rules for slug using regex. [See here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#advanced-routing-example)